# C++, что именно возвращают методы fstream::tellp() / tellg()?

Tags: c++, fstream

Я бы хотел кое в чем разобраться.

У меня есть два потока `fstream`:

```
fstream ftxt{"txt", ios_base::out};
fstream fbin{"bin", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary};
```

Я хочу писать в поток `ftxt` строки, а в поток `fbin` позиции, где строки заканчиваются.

Проблема заключается в том, что `fstream::tellp()` возвращает значение шаблонного типа, толкового описания которого мне найти не удалось, однако мне удалось найти информацию, в которой говорится, что с этим значением нельзя работать, как с целым числом.

То есть, как я понял:

```
const size_t ppos = ftxt.tellp();
fbin << ppos;
```

Является не совсем правильным кодом.

Это действительно так?

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/tellp - написано что `pos_type`

Comment: код выше очевидно неверный, хотя бы потому что на 32-х/64-х битных платформах запишет разное количество байт, а на 32-х-битных даёт UB для для файлов больше 4G... на сколько я понимаю `std::basic_ios::pos_type` — это [`std::fpos<что-то-там>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos), микс из смещения и состояния потока, а числовым типом, гарантированно достаточным для представления смещения является [`std::streamoff`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff), в который `std::fpos` всегда можно преобразовать...

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/, но здесь используют код вроде того, который привел я. И даже не с `size_t`, а `long`.